# IE6 dropping session information when moving from .aspx to .asp page

Tags: asp.net, session, asp-classic, internet-explorer-6

So this is the problem:

We have an application that has both .asp and .aspx pages. When a user is browsing to the site using IE6, there is a possibility that the page will drop the session and the user gets an  or the login page. This doesn't happen all of the time; only sometimes. But I have only been able to replicate on IE6.

Sometimes, when I get the error "This page cannot be displayed," all what I have to do is refresh and it works.

I also notice that when the problem happens, it seems like the site takes a bit longer. Could this be a timeout problem?

Thanks in advance,

Hugo

Comment: How are you sharing Session State between Classic ASP and ASP.NET?  This does not occur by default.  http://www.asp101.com/articles/sidney/sharingsessionstate/default.asp

Comment: There is code that will create asp classic/asp.net sessions states if one is moving from an .aspx page to a .asp page.

Comment: I would love to see that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this could be a timeout problem, if the client spends enough time in purely ASP pages then the ASP.NET session will timeout and vice versa.

However the "The page cannot be displayed" would indicate you have another problem as well and I can't see how this would be a purely IE6 issue.

Comment: Your comment on timeout has been very insightful. Maybe it is dropping because it fails to create the ASP session to begin with.

I  finished testing it again, and I noticed that the .asp page either loaded quickly or it lagged and returned the error. But if it loaded quickly, then I could back and forth .asp and .aspx pages with no trouble.

On the ie6 comment, that is the strange thing, I only see the problem when I test with IE6. And I am testing with two identical virtual machines whose only difference is that I installed ie7 on one of them. Maybe ie6 is a bit slower than ie7 or ie8?

Comment: Crazy. The problem doesn't happen if I am running fiddler, but it happens if I do.

Comment: Yeah, that is one of the annoying aspects of using fiddler, try turning streaming mode on in fiddler by default its off which signficantly changes the timing aspects.  It still changes some timing though being a proxy and I've known security to work differently with Fiddler running.

Comment: Hi, Anthony,

I got an http 504 error. I checked the networking configs for the virtual machines, and the IE6 machine had a bridge configuration (I am using virtualbox). I changed this, and now I don't see this error. 

Thanks so much! Users are having similar problems, and now I have a better insight on what is going on. :)